# What is Nara's Strategy?

Tags: naruto

Before the Allied Shinobi Forces HQ was

> destroyed and scene goes to the Four Hokages with Sasuke, Orochimaru and the others,

was there is a strategy from Nara to be executed. If so, what is this strategy?

As I remember when the scene goes back to the war,

> Naruto and others have difficulty fighting against Madara and Tobi with no any sign of Nara's strategy.

Comment: Haha,:) very interesting. UP!

Comment: We currently don't know what this strategy is. or it hasn't been explicitly mentioned as far as i know.

Comment: wasn't that the strategy to distribute kyuubi's chakra to everyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nara's strategy had four components:

1. Shinobi Alliance create distractions
2. Naruto powering shinobi up with chakra
3. Locking down the Juubi with the Shika Ino Chouji combo
4. The entire Alliance will attack full force at the Juubi

Naruto comes into communication with Shikaku here, as he shares his great Nara Plan. He also stated that he has told the entire alliance his plan already. However, the entirety of the plan is not revealed to the reader just yet. What they are discussing in this chapter is simply creating the distraction.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/95742_naruto-chapter-612/page_9

Phase 2 of the plan begins here as Naruto starts to transfer his chakra to the Shinobi Alliance.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/96726_naruto-chapter-615/page_20

Then phase 3 begins. Chouji is the front line tank along with many others. Ino uses her jutsu to take control of Obito and slightly throw off the Juubi's attacks. And Shikamaru and his clan use the shadowbinding technique on the Juubi. Also note that Shikamaru suspects that something may go wrong with this strategy and (in the flashback) Shikaku basically tells Shikamaru he is going to have to make that decision when the time comes.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/97954_naruto-chapter-616/page_13

Phase 4 commences and the Alliance begins their attack.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/98410_naruto-chapter-617/page_8

That pretty much sums everything up about Nara's strategy. The only problem was that it didn't work. Obito, Madara, and the Juubi are too strong to be taken down by the current Shinobi Alliance. That's when Minato shows up, followed by the other Kages and Sasuke and then everything changes again.

---

Additional proof Shikaku understood the Kyuubi's chakra transfering ability.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/97954_naruto-chapter-616/page_8

Shikaku first learned of it from Kakashi's experience here.
http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/98410_naruto-chapter-617/page_5

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you are not up-to-date with the manga, so I'll put the answer in a spoiler block.

> Shikaku  figured out how the chakra of the Nine Tailed Fox can be shared with other shinobis, giving them extra power, so that they can provide better backup to the main warriors.

Note: This is only an abridged version of the entire plan. The plan in action starts from chapter 614 of the manga, and then the next instance is in the last page of ch 615. Finally ch 616 shows it all.

Comment: As you say **shikaku** figured that out. there is nothing that indicates that Nara told him that. can you give us the chapter this is being told.

Comment: @Robin check the edit. Also Nara relays the message just in the nick of time.

Comment: @debal: You guys know that "Nara" is the surname, right? He's called Shikamaru (the son) or Shikaku (the father)

Comment: @Robin That's like saying Minato was the Fourth Hokage, there's nothing to indicate Namikaze had anything to do with it. I am sorry I don't really follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha oh yes i do. :)